# J (Tacit) Sieve Of Eratosthenes

Tags: primes, j, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm looking for a J code to do the following.

Suppose I have a list of random integers (sorted),
2 3 4 5 7 21 45 49 61
I want to start with the first element and remove any multiples of the element in the list then move on to the next element cancel out its multiples, so on and so forth.

Thus the output
I'm looking at is 2 3 5 7 61. Basically a Sieve Of Eratosthenes. Would appreciate if someone could explain the code as well, since I'm learning J and find it difficult to get most codes :(

Regards,
babsdoc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not exactly what you ask but here is a more idiomatic (and **much** faster) version of the Sieve.

Basically, what you need is to check which number is a multiple of which. You can get this from the table of modulos: `|/~`

```
l =: 2 3 4 5 7 21 45 49 61
|/~ l
  0 1 0 1 1  1  1  1  1
  2 0 1 2 1  0  0  1  1
  2 3 0 1 3  1  1  1  1
  2 3 4 0 2  1  0  4  1
  2 3 4 5 0  0  3  0  5
  2 3 4 5 7  0  3  7 19
  2 3 4 5 7 21  0  4 16
  2 3 4 5 7 21 45  0 12
  2 3 4 5 7 21 45 49  0
```

Every pair of multiples gives a `0` on the table. Now, we are not interested in the `0`s that correspond to self-modulos (2 mod 2, 3 mod 3, etc; the `0`s on the diagonal) so we have to remove them. One way to do this is to add `1`s on their place, like so:

```
=/~ l
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
(=/~l) + (|/~l)
  1 1 0 1 1  1  1  1  1
  2 1 1 2 1  0  0  1  1
  2 3 1 1 3  1  1  1  1
  2 3 4 1 2  1  0  4  1
  2 3 4 5 1  0  3  0  5
  2 3 4 5 7  1  3  7 19
  2 3 4 5 7 21  1  4 16
  2 3 4 5 7 21 45  1 12
  2 3 4 5 7 21 45 49  1
```

This can be also written as `(=/~ + |/~) l`.

From this table we get the final list of numbers: every number whose column contains a `0`, is excluded.

We build this list of exclusions simply by multiplying by column. If a column contains a `0`, its product is `0` otherwise it's a positive number:

```
*/ (=/~ + |/~) l
   256 2187 0 6250 14406 0 0 0 18240
```

Before doing the last step, we'll have to improve this a little. There is no reason to perform long multiplications since we are only interested in `0`s and `not-0`s. So, when building the table, we'll keep only `0`s and `1`s by taking the "sign" of each number (this is the [`signum`:`*`](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d110.htm)):

```
* (=/~ + |/~) l
  1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

so,

```
*/ * (=/~ + |/~) l
  1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
```

From the list of exclusion, you just `copy`:`#` the numbers to your final list:

```
l #~ */ * (=/~ + |/~) l
   2 3 5 7 61
```

or,

```
(]#~[:*/[:*=/~+|/~) l
   2 3 5 7 61
```

Comment: I agree that this is a more natural approach in J, and think it's particularly important to learn to favor whole-array techniques.

Comment: Thank you Both Eelvex and Kaleidic, I'm going to try both these solutions and improvise, definitely looks like a good starting point for me. The explanations you both gave are also very good and detailed, thanks for taking time out. Much appreciated. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2):

Tacit iteration is usually done with the conjunction [Power](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d202n.htm). When the test for completion needs to be something other than hitting a fixpoint, the [Do While](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/Do%20While) construction works well.

In this solution `filterMultiplesOfHead` is applied repeatedly until there are no more numbers not either applied or filtered. Numbers already applied are accumulated in a partial answer. When the list to be processed is empty the partial answer is the result, after stripping off the boxing used to segregate processed from unprocessed data.

```
   filterMultiplesOfHead=: {. (((~: >.)@ %~) # ]) }.
   appendHead=: (>@[ , {.@>@])/
   pass=: appendHead ; filterMultiplesOfHead@>@{:
   prep=: a: , <
   unfinished=: [: -. a: -: {:
   sieve=: [: ; [: pass^:unfinished^:_ prep

   sieve 2 3 4 5 7 21 45 49 61 
2 3 5 7 61

   prep 2 3 4 7 9 10
┌┬────────────┐
││2 3 4 7 9 10│
└┴────────────┘
   appendHead prep 2 3 4 7 9 10
2
   filterMultiplesOfHead 2 3 4 7 9 10
3 7 9
   pass^:2 prep 2 3 4 7 9 10
┌───┬─┐
│2 3│7│
└───┴─┘
   sieve 1-.~/:~~.>:?.$~100
2 3 7 11 29 31 41 53 67 73 83 95 97
```

Comment: I'm doing a `sieve 1-.~/:~~.>:?$~100` and I'm getting some multiples that I shouldn't. I can't see why...

Comment: What I posted originally only filtered prime factors, which was incorrect. I've changed this to filter out every number for which the examined number is a factor. Thank you for alerting me to the problem